# Is there a way to send ZPL (Zebra Programming Language) to a printer in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, sockets, zebra-printers, zpl

Hi everybody i have a question, I made an Android Studio aplication with java to send an label to a printer with ZPL code but dont work, but java code in eclipse it work and create a label. can you help me please. I created a a socket on java with eclipse and DataStream id tried many codes online but it did'nt work.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.swing.*;

//import LaminaMarcoCliente.EnviaTexto;


public class Cliente {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        MarcoCliente mimarco=new MarcoCliente();
        
        mimarco.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

}


class MarcoCliente extends JFrame{
    
    public MarcoCliente(){
        
        setBounds(600,300,280,350);
                
        LaminaMarcoCliente milamina=new LaminaMarcoCliente();
        
        add(milamina);
        
        setVisible(true);
        }   
    
}

class LaminaMarcoCliente extends JPanel{
    
    public LaminaMarcoCliente(){
    
        JLabel texto=new JLabel("CLIENTE");
        
        add(texto);
    
        campo1=new JTextField(20);
    
        add(campo1);        
    
        miboton=new JButton("Enviar");
        
        EnviaTexto mievento = new EnviaTexto();
        
        miboton.addActionListener(mievento);
        
        add(miboton);   
        
    }
    
    
private class EnviaTexto implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        System.out.println("Hola Funciona");
            
        try {
            Socket misocket = new Socket("192.168.14.140", 9100);
            DataOutputStream flujo_salida = new  DataOutputStream(misocket.getOutputStream());
            //flujo_salida.writeUTF(campo1.getText());
            flujo_salida.writeUTF("zpl = \"\"\"\r\n"
                    + "^XA\r\n"
                    + "^CI28\r\n"
                    + "^MMT\r\n"
                    + "^PW406\r\n"
                    + "^LL406\r\n"
                    + "^LS0\r\n"
                    + "^FT5,60^A0N,50,40^FDHELLO LABEL^FS\r\n"
                    + "^FO1,70^BY3^BCN,130,Y,N,N^FD1234567890^FS\r\n"
                    + "^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ\r\n"
                    + "\"\"\"");
                
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
        } 
            
    }

        
    }
        
        
        
    private JTextField campo1;
    
    private JButton miboton;
    
}
```

This is the java code it works on eclipse but in android studio i cant make it works.

regards,

Comment: What do you mean by "works in Eclipse"? Eclipse is an IDE not a runtime platform.   A think you are actually asking about how to make it work on the Android runtime / on an Android device.  And I can see that your code is using AWT rather than the Android APIs.  So really, your question is how to write an Android app that talks to a printer (via a socket connection, I presume).

Comment: Yes that is i need, i put the java example to explain my question.

Comment: Well ... the first thing you need to do is read a tutorial on writing Android apps.  Most of your code will need to be rewritten.

Comment: I'm new on this and i don't have much experience on develop butThank you very much for your advice, I will take it into consideration.